# iOS8: Cannot able to add/show child view controllers view in iOS8

Tags: ios, ios8, viewcontroller

I have a strange problem particularly in iOS8. I have a view controllers which shows content that came from other view controllers. This is what I am currently doing:

```
     ViewController *childViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatientDetailsView" bundle:nil];
    [childViewController setPatient:patient];

   [self.view addSubview:patientDetailsViewController.view];
```

This above line of code runs fine on devices prior to iOS8 but on iOS8 application got stuck on addSubView method and no exception has been thrown by the compiler.

I am not using storyboard in my project so cannot use container view controller to add a child view controller.

Answer (score 1):

try this code

`ViewController *childViewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"PatientDetailsView" bundle:nil];
 [self addChildViewController:childViewController];
 [self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];
 [childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];`

Hope this helps.